# Console.logging and then returning the console.log within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, return, console.log

Apologies, I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to phrase it correctly to find an answer. I was trying to learn Javascript from Udemy and there's a question where you have to return this triangle made from asterisks where the first line is 1 asterisk, 2nd line is 2, 3rd line is 3 etc up until 10 lines of asterisks.
[see this link if I'm not clear enough](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud803/lessons/a7c5b540-51a6-44dc-b2f2-515c9dd6ca4f/concepts/c746623a-eefd-4518-9890-2c5f320b0282)

I can console.log the triangle, but I can't seem to return it once I have console logged it. Please can someone explain where I need to place the return. I've tried everything I can think of and keep getting undefined or no answer once I add in the return for the "buildTriangle function".

```js
    
   /*
     * Programming Quiz: Build A Triangle (5-3)
 */

// creates a line of * for a given length
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
   
}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(length){
    var tri='';
    for(i=0;i<=length;i++){
        tri=console.log(makeLine(i));
    }
    return tri;
    
}


// test your code by uncommenting the following line
buildTriangle(10);
```

Comment: Hi, so what is your goal? Do you just need to log the result? Or do you basically want to return it and display it in your html?

Comment: console.log does not return anything and once you fix that you will realize that your method only returns the last run of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `console.log()` method it will return `undefined` (which you can see in the [console spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger)). Instead, you need to add the return of `makeLine(i)` onto your `tri` string (using `+=`) every time your loop iterates (to build it up into one large triangle). Then, once you're done,  return that built-up string.

In addition to this, you should use `var/let` in front of your declarations in your loop and start the loop at `i=1` as you don't want a line of zero stars in your resulting string:

```js
/*
 * Programming Quiz: Build A Triangle (5-3)
 */

// creates a line of * for a given length
function makeLine(length) {
  let line = "";
  for (let j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    line += "* ";
  }
  return line + "\n";

}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(length) {
  let tri = '';
  //   \/ -- add let/var here (doesn't effect output in this case) and initialize it to 1
  for (let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    tri += makeLine(i); // call makeLine(i) which returns a string
  }
  return tri; // return the triangle string
}


// test your code by uncommenting the following line
console.log(buildTriangle(10)); // log the string
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first build the triangle and then log it, i.e. concatenate all the lines in your triangle variable and return that:

```
// creates a line of * for a given length
function makeLine(length) {
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
      line += "* ";
  }
  return line + "\n";

}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(length){
  var tri='';
  for(i=0;i<=length;i++){
      tri+=(makeLine(i));
  }
  return tri;
}


// test your code by uncommenting the following line
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```